# Querying multiple points on a bivariate spline in the B-spline basis

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to construct a 3D `B-spline` surface and sample it multiple times at various parametric coordinates. The nearest solution I found was to use [`bisplev`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplev.html#scipy.interpolate.bisplev), which expects a `tck` input calculated by [`bsplprep`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html#scipy.interpolate.bisplrep). Unfortunately i cannot use that `tck` component because it produces a surface that passes through the control points, while what I want is a surfaces computed in the `B-spline` `basis`. So I manually construct the `tck` input `bsplev` can use to produce the desired surface.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do this without using 2 nested loops: 1 for each `uv` query, and one for each spacial component. The latter is acceptable but the former is very slow when dealing with very large query arrays.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as si

def bivariate_bspline(cv,u,v,uCount,vCount,uDegree,vDegree):
    # cv = grid of control vertices
    # u,v = list of u,v component queries
    # uCount, vCount = number of control points along the u and v directions
    # uDegree, vDegree = curve degree along the u and v directions
    
    uMax = uCount-uDegree # Max u parameter
    vMax = vCount-vDegree # Max v parameter
    
    # Calculate knot vectors for both u and v
    u_kv = np.clip(np.arange(uCount+uDegree+1)-uDegree,0,uCount-uDegree) # knot vector in the u direction
    v_kv = np.clip(np.arange(vCount+vDegree+1)-vDegree,0,vCount-vDegree) # knot vector in the v direction
    
    # Compute queries
    position = np.empty((u.shape[0], cv.shape[1]))
    for i in xrange(cv.shape[1]):
        tck = (u_kv, v_kv, cv[:,i], uDegree,vDegree)
        
        for j in xrange(u.shape[0]):
            position[j,i] = si.bisplev(u[j],v[j], tck)

    return position
```

Test:

```
# A test grid of control vertices
cv = np.array([[-0.5       , -0.  ,        0.5       ],
               [-0.5       , -0.  ,        0.33333333],
               [-0.5       , -0.  ,        0.        ],
               [-0.5       ,  0.  ,       -0.33333333],
               [-0.5       ,  0.  ,       -0.5       ],
               [-0.16666667,  1.  ,        0.5       ],
               [-0.16666667, -0.  ,        0.33333333],
               [-0.16666667,  0.5 ,        0.        ],
               [-0.16666667,  0.5 ,       -0.33333333],
               [-0.16666667,  0.  ,       -0.5       ],
               [ 0.16666667, -0.  ,        0.5       ],
               [ 0.16666667, -0.  ,        0.33333333],
               [ 0.16666667, -0.  ,        0.        ],
               [ 0.16666667,  0.  ,       -0.33333333],
               [ 0.16666667,  0.  ,       -0.5       ],
               [ 0.5       , -0.  ,        0.5       ],
               [ 0.5       , -0.  ,        0.33333333],
               [ 0.5       , -0.5 ,        0.        ],
               [ 0.5       ,  0.  ,       -0.33333333],
               [ 0.5       ,  0.  ,       -0.5       ]])

uCount = 4
vCount = 5
uDegree = 3
vDegree = 3

n = 10**4 # make 10k random queries
u = np.random.random(n) * (uCount-uDegree) 
v = np.random.random(n) * (vCount-vDegree) 
bivariate_bspline(cv,u,v,uCount,vCount,uDegree,vDegree) # will return n correct samples on a b-spline basis surface
```

Speed test:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('bivariate_bspline(cv,u,v,uCount,vCount,uDegree,vDegree)') # 0.929 seconds
```

So nearly 1 sec for 10k samples, where the `bisplev` call takes the lion's share of computation time because it's being called 10k times for each space component.

I did try to replace the `for j in xrange(u.shape[0]):` loop with a single `bisplev` call giving it the u and v arrays in one go, but that raises a `ValueError: Invalid input data` at `scipy\interpolate\_fitpack_impl.py", line 1048, in bisplev`.

## Question

Is there a way to get rid both, or at minimum the `uv` query loop and do all the `uv` queries in a single vectorized operation?

Comment: What goes wrong if you try `si.bisplev(u, v, tck)`? The method `bisplev` is supposed to accept arrays.

Comment: @Desire it raises a `ValueError("Invalid input data")` at `scipy\interpolate\_fitpack_impl.py", line 1048, in bisplev
  raise ValueError("Invalid input data")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: replace

```
for i in xrange(cv.shape[1]):
    tck = (u_kv, v_kv, cv[:,i], uDegree,vDegree)
    for j in xrange(u.shape[0]):
        position[j,i] = si.bisplev(u[j],v[j], tck)
```

with

```
for i in xrange(cv.shape[1]):
    position[:, i] = si.dfitpack.bispeu(u_kv, v_kv, cv[:,i], uDegree, vDegree, u, v)[0]
```

#### Explanation

`bisplev` does accept arrays as `si.bisplev(u, v, tck)`, but it interprets them as defining an xy-grid. Hence, `u` and `v` must be sorted in ascending order, and evaluation will be performed on all pairs `(u[j], v[k])`, the output being a 2D array of values. This is not what you want; squaring the number of evaluations is probably bad, and it's not going to be easy to extract the values you actually want from the 2D array returned (they are not necessarily on the diagonal, since your u, v were not sorted to begin with).

But the [call method of SmoothBivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.__call__) includes a boolean parameter `grid`, setting which to False makes it just evaluate the spline at `(u[j], v[j])` pairs. The vectors u, v no longer need to be sorted, but now they must be of the same size.

But you are preparing your own `tck`. This presents two approaches: seek to instantiate `SmoothBivariateSpline` with hand-made tck; or read the source of [its call method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.__call__) and do what it does when the parameter `grid` is set to False. I went with the latter approach.

Comment: thanks you!!! huge performance improvement! unless there's a way to also get rid of the loop for each space dimension, this wins!

Comment: @user6655984 would this work then: `tck = si.bisplrep(x,y,z); tx, ty, c, kx, ky = tck; z_q = si.dfitpack.bispeu(tx, ty, c, kx, ky, x_q, y_z)[0]` for `x_q, y_q` the query vectors?